# Prevent certain types from appearing in folder listings in plone.app.theming

Tags: plone, theming, diazo

I have a site which has a public url displayed through a plone.app.theming / Diazo theme and url restricted to content editors displayed through sunburst.

I'd like certain portal types to only appear in listings to the cms editors and not on the public site.  I notice that the folder_listing template uses `request/contentFilter` if defined.  Is there some way to add a content filter to the request just for the themed view?

Comment: In theory this is possible and done in Web and Mobile add-on using monkey-patching of low level folder listing functions. But I do not recommend. More sane approach (meaning: not blowing up on your face) would be just change folder listing template to decorate those items with some CSS class for which you use display: none in your theme.

Comment: Why not use workflows and permissions to keep these items private? That way visitors won't be able to guess the URLs either..

Comment: The items are images and files.  They're not private we just have a requirement for them not to appear in the folder listings.  I already make them non searchable, which until Plone 4.1.5 meant they didn't appear in folder listings either.

Comment: Rather than exclude them using css I can exclude them using a Diazo rule.  It just feels like it would be more elegant to do this using the inbuilt `contentFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a pre traversal hook on the Plone site.  This worked in my case because I can reliably work out whether a request is for the theme view or editing view based on some properties of the request.

```python
def SetupThemeView(site, before_traverse):
    """ If we're serving the public, themed, version then supplement the request
    """
    request = before_traverse.request
    if serving_theme_view(request):
        request.set('contentFilter', {'portal_type' : listable_types})
```

Where `serving_theme_view` determines if we're serving the theme or editor view and `listable_types` is a tuple of type names of types we want to appear in listings in the theme view.

I then register this as a subcriber in my configure.zcml

```xml
<subscriber
    for="Products.CMFCore.interfaces.ISiteRoot
         zope.traversing.interfaces.IBeforeTraverseEvent"
    handler=".events.SetupThemeView"
    />
```